# How to properly render the information in two separate tables coming from two different databases(tables) into the same component

Tags: reactjs

I have a form to add clients to a database and the results are shown at the end of the page; the list is displayed using componentDidMount(). I also have a separate form to manage employees. In this form I add the employees to the other database but the results are being displayed on the same fields as the clients table, and when this happens, the clients information gets hidden.

I am putting them in two different places, so I don't understand why is this happening. I also wanted to mention that the employees form is being imported from another component. Here is some of my code:

```
render() {


    const employees = this.state.employees;
    const employeesList = employees.length ? (
        employees.map(employee => {
            return (
                <div key={employee.id}>
                    <div className="employee-list">
                        <table style={{ width: "60%", tableLayout: "fixed", border: "1px", background: "grey" }}>
                        <React.Fragment>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style={{ width: "50px", textAlign: "center" }}>{employee.id}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "100px", textAlign: "center" }}>{employee.firstName}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "100px", textAlign: "center" }}>{employee.lastName}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "100px", textAlign: "center" }}>{employee.email}</td>
                                    <td><Link style={{ width: "70px", border: "1px solid white" }} className="btn btn-info" to={'/auth/employees/' + employee.id}>Edit
                                </Link>

                                        <button style={{ background: "red", color: "white", width: "70px" }} className="btn btn-warning" onClick={(e) => { if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you wish to delete ${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName} permanently?`)) this.handleDeleteEmployee(employee.id) }}>
                                            Delete
                                </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </React.Fragment>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    ) : (
            <div >No Employees in database</div>
        );

    const clients = this.state.clients;

    const clientsList = clients.length ? (
        clients.map(client => {
            return (
                <div key={client.id}>
                    <div className="card-content">
                        <table style={{ width: "100%", tableLayout: "fixed", border: "1px", background: "white" }}>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style={{ width: "50px", textAlign: "center" }}>{client.id}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "100px", textAlign: "center" }}>{client.lastName}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "100px", textAlign: "center" }}>{client.firstName}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "100px", textAlign: "center" }}>{client.phone}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "160px", textAlign: "center" }}>{client.petName}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "120px", textAlign: "center" }}>{client.breed}</td>
                                    <td style={{ width: "367px", textAlign: "center" }}>{client.notes}</td>
                                    <td><Link style={{ width: "70px", border: "1px solid white" }} className="btn btn-info" to={'api/clients/' + client.id}>Edit
                                </Link>

                                        <button style={{ background: "red", color: "white", width: "70px" }} className="btn btn-warning" onClick={(e) => { if (window.confirm(`Are you sure you wish to delete ${client.firstName} ${client.lastName} permanently?`)) this.handleDeleteClient(client.id) }}>
                                            Delete
                                </button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        })
    ) : (
            <div >No clients in database</div>
        );


 return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">

                    <hr style={{ background: "white" }}></hr>
                    <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}><b>Welcome to the Admin Panel Paola</b></h1>

                    <Button color="warning" style={{ fontSize: "20px", color: "navy", border: "solid 1px navy", marginBottom: "15px" }} onClick={this.handleLogOut}>Logout</Button>
                    <Button style={{ fontSize: "20px", background: "navy", marginLeft: "15px", marginBottom: "15px" }} onClick={this.toggleEmployeeFormFunction}>Add new Staff members (click to hide/show)</Button>
                    {
                        this.state.toggleEmployeeForm ? (
                            <div><EmployeeSignupForm>
                            </EmployeeSignupForm> 
                            {employeesList}
                            </div>
                        ) : (
                                null
                            )
                    }

<div className="col-md-8 bg-dark" style={{ border: '1px solid white', color: 'white', marginBottom: "30px" }}>
                    <form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)} style={{ marginBottom: "50px" }}>
                        <h2 className="grey-text text-darken-3" style={{ textAlign: "center", marginTop: "15px" }}>Add a New Client</h2>
                        <p>* Fields required</p>
                        <hr style={{ background: "white" }}></hr>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="lastName">* Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id='lastName' value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="firstName">* First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id='firstName' value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="phone">* Phone</label>
                            <input type="text" id='phone' value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="petName">* Pet Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id='petName' value={this.state.petName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="breed">* Breed</label>
                            <input type="text" id='breed' value={this.state.breed} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <label htmlFor="notes">Notes</label>
                            <input type="text" id='notes' value={this.state.notes} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                            <button className="btn-primary lighten-1 z-depth-0" onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
                            >Add Client</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="row">

                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <div style={{ background: "white", paddingTop: "12px", marginBottom: "100px" }}>
                            <h6><b>
                            <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Clients List</h1>
                                <span style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "8px 17px 8px 17px" }}>Id</span>
                                <span style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "8px 11px 8px 12px" }}>Last Name</span>
                                <span style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "8px 8px 8px 8px" }}> First Name</span>
                                <span style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "8px 27px 8px 25px" }}>Phone</span>
                                <span style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "8px 44px 8px 44px" }}>Pet Name</span>
                                <span style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "8px 37px 8px 38px" }}>Breed</span>
                                <span style={{ border: "1px solid", padding: "8px 200px 8px 200px", background: "white" }}>Notes / Actions</span>
                            </b></h6>
                            {clientsList}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div >
    )

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show how you're handling the component state? It could be that `state.employees` is getting deleted when `state.clients` is set, and vice versa.

Comment: that was exactly my issue. I was resetting the client state on one of my functions. Thanks